# Show error if form is submitted

Tags: php, forms

I'm wanting my form to show an error such as "Enter first name" if the field has not being filled in. I have got to right code(I think) to do this but it is showing the error when the page is first loaded. I want it to be displayed when the form has been submitted.

```
    <div class="Row">
<div class="Lable">First Name:</div> <!--End of Lable-->
<div class="input">
<input type="text" id="firstname" class="detail" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name"  />
</div> <!--End input-->
</div> <!--End row-->
<span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
```

The PHP validation is

```
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
 $nameErr = "Name is required";
} else {
 $firstname = test_input($_POST["name"]);
 // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname)) {
   $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
 }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to use `isset` and use it in conjunction with your submit button and/or your `firstname` element.

Comment: `$nameErr` will be undefined on the 1st load. use `empty` or `isset`

Comment: Another option is using HTML5 `required` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would double check the form with **PHP** and **JavaScript**

For the javascript part add this line to your form, so the function `validate()` will run before the forms content will be sent to the server.

```
<form onsubmit="validate()">
```

Then you can add a javascipt function to your document like this:

```
function validate() {
  if (/*check if fields are filled out properly*/) {
    this.submit();
  } else {
    // show message here when fields are missing

    return false; // this line is important otherwise the form gets submitted anyway
  }
}
```

For the PHP part it is enough to check for the differnt fields with `isset()`

This would look like this:

```
$formOK = true;
if (!isset($_POST["field-name-1"]) || $_POST["field-name-1"] == "") {
  echo "field-1 is missing";
  $formOK = false
}
if (!isset($_POST["field-name-2"]) || $_POST["field-name-2"] == "") {
  echo "field-2 is missing";
  $formOK = false
}

if (formOK) {
  echo "everything is fine";
  // do something with your form data
}
```

---

To double check is definitly the best way because first of all you are not having so many requests and the javascript is more flexible in is reactions and speed but the PHP will provide you the guarantee that nothing will go wrong.

Comment: Yes, that is a way to check the form before it is sent. However, you should always double check in php, to avoid potential problems. You could also use the `required` attribute for the inputs, but that is not sufficient.

Comment: thanks for noticing ill change my answer in this way

Comment: If I send the form with empty fields, your code will return "everything is fine". Because you check the fields with `isset`. This method will return true, because the field IS set, even if it is just an empty string. You should also check if it equals to `""`.

Comment: thanks for this and to everyone else for helping. Is answer id the one that I have used and is working. Also iv included some java script is validate the form and this will be what the user will see see if the form is filled out incorrectly. The server side is just for reassurance. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
if (isset($nameErr)) {
    echo '<span class="error">* ' . $nameErr . '</span>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply the validation only if the form was submitted, you could check if you received `$_POST['submit']` this way :

```
<?php
    $nameError="";

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        //validate the form
        if(condition is not met){ $nameError="your error message"; }
    }
?>

<form>
    ...
    <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
    <span class="myError">* <?=$nameError?> </span>
</form>
```

Here, the submit button will send `$_POST['submit']`. The error message at the beginning is empty. If there is an error, change it. `<?=$nameError?>` will then display it whether it is empty or not.

Comment: this wont solve the error. and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is perfectly fine.